# Transferring video stream (/dev/video0) from Linux device to Windows device

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, v4l2

I've got a video stream running on my Raspberry Pi. I'd like to get the video stream on my Windows device by hooking up the Pi with my Windows laptop.

I know there are two standards which sound promising: [GigE Vision and USB Vision](https://www.visiononline.org/vision-standards.cfm). However, I don't know how to implement them. And it seems there are not really open to use for everyone. Is there another way to stream video (/dev/video0) from my Raspberry to my laptop, so that I can open the stream using the VLC player on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You could use gstreamer/vlc to stream the video over network and then use vlc to access the video on windows, refer this [link](http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_Camera) for more details.